# How to identify which radio button is accepted?

Tags: html, radio-button

How can I identify which radio button is accepted?

How do I prevent a user being able to select multiple options when I use radio buttons?

```
<input type='radio' name='one'>option1<br />
<input type='radio' name='two'>option2<br />
<input type='radio' name='three'>option3<br />
<input type='radio' name='four'>option4<br />
<input type='radio' name='five'>option5<br />
```

Thats the code I use, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the "name" attribute to tie them all together, use the value attribute to give them different values.

```
<input type="radio" name="number" value="one" /> One<br />
<input type="radio" name="number" value="two" /> Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="number" value="three" /> Three<br />
```

Think of name as last name... For example, if you had Bart, Lisa, Homer, Marge and Maggie, the name would be their last name: Simpson, the value would be the said names:

```
<input type="radio" name="Simpson" value="Bart" /> Bart<br />
<input type="radio" name="Simpson" value="Lisa" /> Lisa<br />
<input type="radio" name="Simpson" value="Marge" /> Marge<br />
<input type="radio" name="Simpson" value="Homer" /> Homer<br />
<input type="radio" name="Simpson" value="Maggie" /> Maggie<br />
```

Comment: Great answer, very useful.
I will give this the green tick as soon as it allows me.
Thanks bud.

Comment: So what if i need to know which button was selected?
Is that possible?

Comment: The value will be the one which was selected.

Answer (score 4):

you should give them the same name

Answer (score 0):

Also the order of name/value pair matter's I guess.Name should appear before the order

Answer (score 0):

I know! Do like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="a">1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a">2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a">3</label>
```

Give everything same value for 'name' attribute. You add the name for the radio buttons