# asp.net mvc4 RadioButtonList not select multiple radiobutton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I'm working with ASP.net MVC4 with razor and javascript
In this image I can't select multiple radio, when I select an option the other option selected remains clean and not selected.
[image]

and this is my code:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE){
  <tbody>
<tr>
 <td>@item.cprp_descripcion</td>
 <td>@item.piv_cantidad</td>
 <td>@item.cprp_idpartepre</td>
 <td>     
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Bueno, new { id = string.Format("B_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Bueno
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Regular, new { id = string.Format("R_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Regular
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Deficiente, new { id = string.Format("D_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Deficiente                 
     </td>                
 <td>@item.piv_observacion</td>
```

```
}
```

how I can select an option for each row?

this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsInformacionVehiculo(string IdInspeccion)
    {
        ViewBag.IdInspeccion = IdInspeccion;
        List<Models.v_PreInformacionVehi> ListaInfVehi = InformacionVehiculo("INP0001", "", "").ToList();
        List<Models.v_PreInformacionVehi> ListaFrontalExt = ListaInfVehi.Where(e => e.cprp_partipoiv == "E" && e.cprp_parsubtipoiv == "F").ToList();
        ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE = ListaFrontalExt;
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Inspeccion/Views/raAcc/_DatosInfoVehiculo.cshtml");           
    }
```

Where ListaFrontaExt is this data (image) (this send for ViewBag to partialview _DatosInfoVehiculo.cshtml
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a for loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE.Count; i++)
{
  <tbody>
<tr>
 <td>@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_descripcion</td>
 <td>@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].piv_cantidad</td>
 <td>@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_idpartepre</td>
 <td>     
    @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("[{0}].parestadopieza", i), Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Bueno, new { id = string.Format("B_{0}", ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Bueno
    @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("[{0}].parestadopieza", i), Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Regular, new { id = string.Format("R_{0}", ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Regular
    @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("[{0}].parestadopieza", i), Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Deficiente, new { id = string.Format("D_{0}", ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) }) Deficiente                 
     </td>                
 <td>@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].piv_observacion</td>
}
```

The problem is `Html.RadioButtonFor` is generating the same names for all of your radio buttons, so it's treating them as one single group.

Comment: you can feed dynamic name into it using model with the same code

Comment: @ShayanNafisi The helpers are already generating names for the radio buttons internally.  Supplying that as part of `new { name = // ... }` is a duplication of effort.  Let the helpers do the work for you.

Comment: @ShayanNafisi Also, why the downvote?  This is the right solution.

Comment: @ShayanNafisi Thanks.  To explain my comment above about the names, try using `Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Whatever, ...)` and don't supply any `new { name = something }`.  Then check the generated HTML and you'll see that it automatically adds a `name` attribute.

Comment: @ShayanNafisi Haha, no problem.  Just wanted to make sure you understood what I was saying. :)

Comment: Jhon H I have error, when I add @Model[i] this is the message "You can not apply the indexation with an expression []"

Comment: @raranibar Sorry, try this instead: `@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i]`.

Comment: John H @ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i]not function

Comment: @raranibar `@ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE[i].cprp_descripcion` ?

Comment: John H @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE.Count(); i++ ) error 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi>.Count' no invocable. maybe error in @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].parestadopieza, m[i] not apply the indexation with expression []

Comment: @raranibar `@for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE.Count; i++)`

Comment: John H but not recognize @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].parestadopieza, m[i] not apply the indexation with expression []

Comment: John H Thanks now function

Comment: @JohnH Following your suggestion, when I retrieve data from the database does not place value on the radiobutton, but if the textbox, how i can resolve this problem

Comment: @JohnH If you can follow this link to help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974641/asp-net-mvc-radiobutton-retrieve-selected-data

Answer (score 0):

use RadioButton (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492690%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
<ol class="Opt">
@foreach (var opt in quest.Options)
{
    <li>
        @Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", opt.Title)
        @Html.Label(opt.Title)
    </li>
}
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different names for each set

```
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DatosInfVehiFE){
          <tbody>

              <tr>
                  <td>@item.cprp_descripcion</td>
                  <td>@item.piv_cantidad</td>
                  <td>@item.cprp_idpartepre</td>
                  <td>     
                      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Bueno, new { id = string.Format("B_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()) , @name=item.name }) Bueno
                      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Regular, new { id = string.Format("R_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), @name = item.name }) Regular
                      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.parestadopieza, Crd.Web.Areas.Inspeccion.Models.v_PreInformacionVehi.Estado.Deficiente, new { id = string.Format("D_{0}", item.cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), @name = item.name }) Deficiente                 
                  </td>                
                  <td>@item.piv_observacion</td>  
              </tr>

          </tbody>
          }
```

more example: [How to identify which radio button is accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176096/multiple-radio-buttons)

Comment: @Jared: you are right, fixed it. you should set each group with a name and use values to find out which one is selected.

Comment: Hi Shayan Nafise I add @name and not fuction, i can't select multiple radio, only allows me to select a radiobutton