# Asp.net mvc radiobutton retrieve selected data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.net MVC4 with razor and javascript.

I load my view as follow:
When Retrieve data from database not check the values ​​of radiobutton, the radiobutton is empty, How I can resolve this problem? the values ​​is in the Textbox are recovered the radiobutton no.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Parte Frontal</th>
        <th>Cant.</th>
        <th>Bueno</th>
        <th>Regular</th>
        <th>Deficiente</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
    </tr>      
    @{int numitem = 0;} 
    @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal.Count; i++)
    {                                          
        <tr>            
        <td>@ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_descripcion</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox(string.Format("txtpieza{0}", numitem), (int)ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].piv_cantidad, new { id = string.Format("txtpieza{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), style = "width:25px;text-align:right;", onkeyup = "checkInt(this)", sololectura = false })</td>       
        <td class="td-center">               
            @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("rbtestado{0}", numitem), "B", new { id = string.Format("B{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), sololectura = false })                                
        </td>
        <td class="td-center">
            @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("rbtestado{0}", numitem), "R", new { id = string.Format("R{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), sololectura = false })                                
        </td>
        <td class="td-center">
            @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("rbtestado{0}", numitem), "D", new { id = string.Format("D{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), sololectura = false })                                
        </td>                
        <td>@Html.TextBox(string.Format("txtobservacion{0}", numitem), (string)ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].piv_observacion, new { id = string.Format("txtobservacion{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), style = "width:150px;", sololectura = false })</td>
        <td>
        @{                  
            string IdPartePre = String.Format("{0}", numitem);
            string PartePre = String.Format("{0}", (int)ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre);
            numitem++;             
        }  
        <input id="@IdPartePre" type="hidden" name="@PartePre" value="@PartePre"/>
        </td>
        </tr>     

    } 
    </table>
```

Comment: for helpers tie the value to your model.  change your radio buttons to @Html.RadioButtonFor

Comment: check ur controller and show controller action with viewbug

Comment: @MattBodily If I use Html.RadioButtonFor it this generate the same names for all of my radiobuttons and I can't selected more that one radiobutton

Comment: @user1956570 my controller return DatosExtFrontal with current information because load the values ​​in the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can't use a for helper to tie it to your model then you will need to put a unique name on the field and then you can get the value on your controller using

```
Request.Form["RadioName"].ToString()
```

Comment: but the unique name is: @Html.RadioButton(String.Format("rbtestado{0}", numitem), "B", new { id = string.Format("B{0}", ViewBag.DatosExtFrontal[i].cprp_idpartepre.ToString()), sololectura = false })

Comment: look at how the radio button is rendered on the view and make sure the name in the request matches and you should be good